# Autokeras installation with Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, auto-keras

I have problems with installing Autokeras with Anaconda.

- I downgraded python to 3.6
- I installed pytorch and downgraded to
  version 0.4.1
- I downgraded numpy to 1.14.5
- I installed visual studio C++ build tool

But now I get the error that tensorflow will require max numpy version 1.14.5. but autokeras will upgrade numpy to 1.15.4 and it failed to build the wheel for lws

After every step ther was an error. 
Is there a simple, straight forward way to install Autokeras on Annaconda (Win)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

I have Windows 10, Anaconda 2019.10 and Python 3.7.5. In my case, I get the error `ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.0.1.post2 (from autokeras)` on Windows 10 when trying to `pip install autokeras` as indicated by the official documentation.

Then I try to get the source code from https://github.com/keras-team/autokeras and run `python setup.py install`. It successfully installs autokeras for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, using Windows 10 Pro. I installed VMware Workstation 15 Player, installed lubuntu as the guest OS, installed anaconda onto that, created a conda virtual environment, and was able to install autokeras as per https://autokeras.com/start/ . The autokeras installation gave a numpy version error, but seems to work. This might not be the answer you are looking for.

Another answer you might not be looking for is to use Docker, as per https://autokeras.com/docker/ . Once I'd changed "$(pwd)":/app to "$(pwd):/app" in the example, this also seems to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it soon. As usual in the meantime hundred other project tasks came rolling my way :-)